# cocos2djs clean project not working

Tags: android, android-studio, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

Clean cocos project made with

cocos new projectName -l js

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cocos2djs from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Unfortunately libcocos2dx has stopped

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: you have just missed some settings. Try this out 
1.  Build Android Project minSdkVersion >= 9 and your sdk is updated with the same.
2. Check in jni/Application.mk in the project that is created in cocos2d
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 
Save the file to build and clean the project ... See if it works if not let me know which device your are using and if you can provide logs in detail from cmd would be great to help you out.

Comment: thanks I'll try that asap